# How to analyze data with a lot of missing data (including covariate, nesting and blocking)

Tags: missing-data, nested-data, blocking, predictor

I have data set that was haphazardly collected to test grazing impact on soil. To test the grazing impact, 6 replicate soil samples were collected from inside a fence and 6 replicates  were from outside of a fence. However, some area have been fenced only 1 year, while other have fenced 35 years. Those fenced areas spread across a country so they differ in soil texture types and eco zones they belong. As I mentioned earlier, the data was haphazardly collected. So, some eco zones have only two fences which differ in their fenced years and soil texture  types. Some soil texture type is present only in one eco zone but not in others.

Basically, the headers of data are as below:

```
Zones – forest steppe, desert steppe, etc.
Soil texture type – clay, clay loam, etc.
Site_id – denotes the id of fence. Each fence has its own ID and has rested and grazed treatment
Rested_years – indicates how many years the area has been fenced.
Treatment – rested & grazed. Grazed means the data is collected outside of a fence. Rested means the data is collected inside a fence.
Replicate – replicate number 1-6. 
Five_in – soil data at 0-5 cm depth.
```

I am thinking about running separate analyses for each zones since I am not interested in comparing zone. I think zone is big enough to be different (prep, temperature, etc.) So, I can justify why they should not analyzed together. Then, I think soil texture type is included as a random factor and site_id is included as nested factor within a soil texture type. I also thinking about including rested years as a covariate. However, I'm not sure. Any help suggestions will be appreciated